# Sequelize associations not being created in MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite

Tags: mysql, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, associations

I am defining associations in models using sequalize with MYSQL. But after migration, the foreign key is not being added to the target model as explained in sequelize docs.

I have also tried to manually define foreign keys in models and migration files but still no association is being created between tables. When I view the tables in relation view in PhpMyAdmin, not foreign key constraints or relationship is being created.

I have tried this with SQLite, and PostgreSQL with the same results. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here are models.

```
AURHOR MODEL
//One author hasMany books

'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Author = sequelize.define('Author', {
    Name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Author.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Author.hasMany(models.Book)
  };
  return Author;
};
```

I expect sequelize to add authorId on books table as specified in the docs, but this not happening

```
 BOOK MODEL
    //Book belongs to Author
    'use strict';
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const Book = sequelize.define('Book', {
        Title: DataTypes.STRING
      }, {});
      Book.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Book.belongsTo(models.Author)
      };
      return Book;
    };
```

No associations is being created between these two tables after migration.
I have as well tried to define custom foreign keys in model associations like this:

```
//Author model
    Author.hasMany(models.Book,{foreignKey:'AuthorId'})
 //Book model
 Book.belongsTo(models.Author,{foreignKey:'AuthorId'})
```

still this not solving the problem

I have gone ahead to define foreign keys in models then referencing them in the association like this:

```
  'use strict';
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const Book = sequelize.define('Book', {
        Title: DataTypes.STRING,
        AuthorId:DataTypes.INTEGER
      }, {});
      Book.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Book.belongsTo(models.Author,{foreignKey:'AuthorId'})
      };
      return Book;
    };
```

But still no associations is being created

I finally decided to add references in migration files like so:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Books', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      Title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },

      AuthorId:{
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          references:{
          model:'Author',
          key:'id'
          }

      }

      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Books');
  }
};
```

But when I run this kind of migration setup, I get this error: ERROR: Can't create table `dbname`.`books` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is i
ncorrectly formed")

I get similar error when I switch to PostgreSQL.

I have been held back by this issue for quite long. What may I doing wrong. I am using sequelize **version 4.31.2** with sequelize CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was referencing to models wrongly in migrations.
**Wrong way**

```
 AuthorId:{
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          references:{
          model:'Author',
          key:'id'
          }

      }
```

**Correct Way**

```
  // Notes the model value is in lower case and plural just like the table name in the database
     AuthorId:{
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
              references:{
              **model:'authors',**
              key:'id'
              }

      }
```

This solved my problem. The associations is now getting defined.